# How to prove a set is a totally bounded set?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be a separable complete metric space. By separability, for every $n\ge 1$ there exists an open $1/n$ ball sequence $A_{nk}=\{x\in S: d(x,x_k)<1/n\}$ covering $S$, where $x_k\in S, k\ge 1$. $k_n$ is a positive integer depending on $n$. How to prove that $B=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{k\le k_n}A_{nk}$ is a totally bounded set.

Comment: Step 1: recall the definition of a totally bounded set. (Step 2 depends a bit on the specific formulation.)

Comment: The question is from the proof of this theorem:  The probability measure P on the separable complete metric space S is tight.  Proof. By the separability of $S$, for every $n\ge 1$ there exists an open $1/n$ ball sequence $A_{nk}$ covering $S$. So for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $k_n$ such that $P\left\{\bigcup_{k=1}^{k_n}A_{nk}\right\}>1-\varepsilon/2^n$, but 
$B=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{k\le k_n}A_{nk}$ is a totally bounded set and $P(B)>1-\varepsilon$. ... . I want to know how to prove $B$ is a totally bounded set? Thank you.

Comment: Can you write the detailed processes of your proof? @ Daniel Fischer, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtain the following proof, please correct it for me. Thank you.
Proof. For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a positive integer $n'$ such that $1/n'<\varepsilon/2$.
Writing $A_{n'_k}=B(z_k, 1/n')$,  and noting that $B\subset\bigcup_{k\le k_{n'}}A_{n'_k}$, we have $B=\bigcup_{k\le k_{n'}}\left(B\bigcap A_{n'_k}\right)$.
Hence, for every $x\in B$, there exists $k_0\in \{1,2,\cdots,k_{n'}\}, x\in A_{n'_{k_0}}$.
Taking $y_{k_0}\in B\bigcap A_{n'_{k_0}}$, then
$$d\left(x, y_{k_0}\right)\le d\left(x, z_{k_0}\right)+d\left(y_{k_0}, z_{k_0}\right)<1/n'+1/n'<\varepsilon.$$
So, $\tilde{B}=\{y_{k_0}, 1\le k_0\le k_{n'}\}$ is a finite $\varepsilon$-net for $B$. Thus $B$ is a totally bouned set. This completes the proof.