# How to prove the convergence of a series for a weighted random variables?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables, absolute-convergence, almost-everywhere

Let $\{X_n,n\ge 1\}$ be a sequence of independently identically distributed random variables with the same mean $\mu$, $a_n, n\ge 1$ be real numbers. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|<\infty$ then the random series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n X_n$ is convergent a.s.. How to prove its inverse proposition, that is, how to prove that if the random series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n X_n$ is convergent a.s. then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|<\infty$?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true.  If $X_n = \pm 1$, each with probability $1/2$, then it is well known that $\sum_n \frac1n X_n$ converges a.s.  (Special case of Kolmogorov three series theorem.)

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer! Please help me to solve another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841171/how-to-prove-a-set-is-a-totally-bounded-set?noredirect=1#comment7923264_3841171